How to create an Authentication helper in Expo React Native
I am creating an app using Expo React Native that will connect to the spotify API. I followed the rules in the guide provided by Expo when it comes to Authentication with OAuth or OpenID providers and it worked well, but I wanted to tidy up all the AuthSession stuff to a helper. I did this because I didn't want it cluttering up my login page, and I may want to do more with AuthSession. This is how I went about defining my AuthManager helper...
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from "expo-auth-session";
import { Router } from "expo-router";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
  tokenEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
};

const scopes = [
  "streaming",
  "user-read-email",
  "user-read-private",
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-modify-playback-state",
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "playlist-modify-private",
  "playlist-read-private",
  "playlist-modify-public"
];

const clientId = ...

const scheme = ...
const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({ scheme: scheme })

const [request, setRequest] = useState<any>();
const [response, setResponse] =  useState<any>();
const [promptAsync, setPromptAsync] = useState<any>();

export function InitAuthRequest() {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: clientId,
      scopes: scopes,
      usePKCE: false,
      redirectUri: redirectUri
    },
      discovery
  );

  setRequest(request);
  setResponse(response);
  setPromptAsync(promptAsync())
}

export function AuthRedirect(router: Router, onSuccessHref: any) {
  promptAsync();

  if (response?.type === "success") {
    const code  = response.params;
    console.log("Successfully authenticated and obtained access token", code);
    router.replace(onSuccessHref);
  } else {
    console.log("Unable to authenticate");
  }
}

After this, I tried to AuthRedirect and InitAuthRequest in my code for my Login screen...
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { AuthRedirect, InitAuthRequest } from "../helpers/auth-manager";


export default function Login() {
  InitAuthRequest;
  const router = useRouter(); 

  const verifySpotifyUser = () => {
    AuthRedirect(router, "/screens/home");
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Button
        title="Connect to Spotify"
        onPress={verifySpotifyUser}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


I cannot get the helper and the login page to cooperate with each other though! The 'problem child' here is the const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest part. If I try to...

Initialise the AuthRequest in my AuthRedirect function, I break the rules of hooks as I am calling the hook within the OnPress event handler
If I move the AuthRedirect outside of a function, I get a Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') error
When I try to use the function, InitAuthRequest to initialise the AuthRequest, I get an error saying that promptAsync is not a function, or I get a "breaking the rules of hooks" error saying Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. (Even though the InitAuthRequest is not called at the top of my Login page function and seemingly not in a hook?)

I am a little confused about where I have gone wrong with my approach to creating my AuthManager helper so I will be grateful for any feedback/help! Thank you in advance.
